# How do I query effective permissions on an Active Directory Object?

Tags: permissions, active-directory, exchange-server, adsi

I'm trying to programmatically determine whether the current user has certain permissions on a given Active Directory object (specifically in this case, I'm trying to determine whether the user has the "Send As" permission for another Exchange user or distribution list object).

I already figured out how to access the `ntSecurityDescriptor` attribute using ADSI: I can enumerate the ACEs in the `IADsSecurityDescriptor`'s `DiscretionaryACL` property. But:

- How do I determine from that data whether the "Send As"-permission is explicitly allowed or denied for a trustee?
- How do I discover this when the permission has been granted indirectly via group membership? Do I really have to parse the effective permissions myself by (recursively) checking all groups the user is a member of? Surely there must be an API for that task...

FWIW, I'm coding in Delphi (i.e. native Win32 code) using the ActiveDs.dll typelibrary, so .NET-specific solutions won't really help me much unless their source code gives me clues to how to do the same thing in native code. The same goes for PowerShell.

---

Before anyone starts: I already know about the `PR_EMS_AB_PUBLIC_DELEGATES` and `PR_EMS_AB_PUBLIC_DELEGATES_BL_O` Extended MAPI properties. However, this is not what I'm after. These properties refer to the "Send on behalf of"-right (a.k.a. delegates), not the "Send As" permission, which is quite a different thing.

Comment: @RRUZ : Thanks for stepping in but I'd rather keep the delphi-tag out of this, especially as some of the people able to answer this might even have it in their ignore list. I expect the eventual solution to be equally applicable to any programming language that can consume COM.

Comment: Delphi-specific follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8524507/9784

Answer (score 2):

Here's the MSDN article that explains - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675580(v=VS.85).aspx. There is an attached sample that shows how to call the API.

Comment: Thanks, that looks very promising! Unfortunately, I won't have time to try this out until the week after next. I'll get back with the results (and hopefully an upvote and an accept) as soon as I know more.

Comment: OK, I've now gotten a tiny bit further (it took a while for me to convert the example code to Delphi). I managed to create an example that compiles and runs but, being completely new to Windows security, I can't really say I understand what I'm doing or even what exactly it is I'm checking with this procedure... :(

Comment: I'm sure I won't get around getting to to know the underlying concepts in the mid- to long term but I was hoping for a slightly more high-level approach to get me started. Ideally, I want to pass in an object SID and an access mask (though I still need to figure out, what I should be checking for in my particular case, i.e. the Exchange-specific "Send As"-right - I'm sure there must be a header file with constants for this, isn't there?) and get back `True` or `False` (I don't need to verify access for any user other than the current one).

Comment: While looking into this example and how to translate it to Delphi I've also stumbled across the AuthZ-API. Would that also provide the functionality I need and if so, would there be any benefit in doing so?
I was also wondering why the example was using `AccessCheckByObjectTypeResultList` rather than just `AccessCheck` or any of its other variations. The MSDN-summaries for these are almost identical... :-/

Comment: I think I've gotten quite a bit further in my understanding but I still can't get it to work. Apparently my Delphi translation of the example is still incorrect in some way: When I call `AccessCheckByObjectTypeResultList` it always fails and Last Error is 87 ("The parameter is incorrect") - yet I have no idea which of the bazillion parameters that this function accepts it is complaining about here... :(